# Is it possible to resize the forms and the layouts in proportion with screen resolution in window forms we are using devexpress controls

Tags: asp.net, windows, window, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

Is there any way to resize the forms and the layouts in proportion with screen resolution.
Because in higher resolution, the forms and the controls become very small.

Comment: You've added tags for both ASP.NET and Windows UI. Can you please clarify if you are developing a Windows (WinForms or WPF) application or a web application (ASP.NET, MVC, HTML5/JS)?

Comment: Do you mean DPI scaling?